# Apple Mail marks email as read

Tags: macos, mail.app

This is very annoying and makes me miss important email. After receiving an email, it's marked as read by the Mavericks Mail App. Anyone bumped into the same issue? Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, do you use a message preview window ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes but this happens without selecting the email/row

Comment: Just for fun, remove the preview window.

Answer (score 1):

I had/have the same issue.  With IMAP email server, if you have another computer, or phone, etc.  checking mail from the same server it marks it as read in Mail.   Change your settings (or remake a profile) to POP instead of IMAP.  Solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problems with OS11 (Big Sur). All of my mail for 1 account was coming in as read and I was missing important messages. I turned off notifications for mail and that seems to have solved the problem for me.